# jQuery: Make strings with varying capitalization Title case

Tags: jquery, css, string

Pretty simple question, but I can't quite seem to find the answer.

I have several HTML pages from differing sources that have strings in their `<h2>` elements with dumb capitalizations. Such as:

`<h2>Are there OTHER USES for this medicine?</h2>`

I'm looking to make these regular sentence case, i.e.,

`<h2>Are there other uses for this medicine?</h2>`

I began by making them all lower case with CSS:

```
h2 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

because I was hoping to then manipulate them with jQuery by making a function that just capitalizes the first letter.

So the question is: How would I write a jQuery function to capitalize just the first letter of each `h2` element on a page?

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript), tried this:

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string){
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

$('h2').each(function(){
  capitaliseFirstLetter($(this).text());
});
```

But it didn't work, and the console didn't give me any errors, so I don't know what's wrong.

**EDIT**

I made one large oversight in this question. Using

`text-transform: lowercase`

made the word I lowercase, so

`<h2>What should I do in case of OVERDOSE?</h2>`

became

`<h2>What should i do in case of overdose?</h2>`

when I used @marcelo-biffara's solution. (Or the `:first-letter` CSS syntax.)

Now, do I need to use a complicated regexp to just capitalize the string " i "?

**EDIT 2**

If there are two occurrences of " i " (such as in "What should i do if i take too many doses?"), do I need a loop to replace them with " I "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make this function

```
function capitalizeMe(val){
    return val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+val.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

oh, and maybe you need to remove you css h2 rule

you can apply it to your h2 like this

```
$('h2').each(function(){
    var str = capitalizeMe($(this).html());
    $(this).html(str);  
});


function replaceAll( text, v1, v2 ){
  while (text.toString().indexOf(v1) != -1)
      text = text.toString().replace(v1,v2);
  return text;
}
```

if you want to capitalize each instance of  "i" you could do something like this

```
$('h2').each(function(){
    var str = replaceAll(capitalizeMe($(this).html())," i "," I ");
    $(this).html(str);  
});
```

Comment: This is great, but it only works if there's one instance of " i " in a sentence. Does it need a loop if it's something like "What should i do if i forget to take a dose?" Add that to your edit, and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: ok, try now , you have to write a custom replaceAll function as shown!

Comment: this solution will fail if the string begins with an "i" and is not already capitalized. Nonetheless, this works for situation stated by OP.

Answer (score 3):

`capitaliseFirstLetter($(this).text());` returns you a string.  That's it.  You're not doing anything with that string.  You need to put the returned string somewhere.

```
$('h2').each(function(){
    var str = capitaliseFirstLetter($(this).text());
    $(this).text(str);  // Set the text of the element
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use CSS

```
h2 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
h2:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CbDHH/

Comment: Forgot to mention I need to support IE8, which doesn't support that pseudo-selector. But that is a great idea!

Comment: @nickcoxdotme from the doc above its supported from IE5.5, though I guess there is a lot to consider if you're going to use `:first-letter`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that worked with the one colon syntax. That's a great solution, and see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the new value of the h2 content:

```
$('h2').each(function(){
  $(this).text(capitaliseFirstLetter($(this).text()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant do anything you just add following css

```
 h2{
       text-transform: lowercase;
    }
```

```css
h2 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Name is xYz</h2>
```